# Where is the mistake in this Finding the inverse of a matrix problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My objective is to discover a square matrix denoted as $P$ that can transform matrix $A$ into echelon form when multiplied with it.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & 3\\
2 & 3 & 2\\
3 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

That is my effort:

$\begin{array}{c}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
2 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow{R_{1}\rightarrow\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)R_{1}}\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
1 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
2 & 3 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
3 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
2 & 2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow[\begin{array}{c}
R_{4}\rightarrow R_{4}-2R_{1}\end{array}]{\begin{array}{c}
\begin{array}{c}
R_{2}\rightarrow R_{2}-2R_{1}\\
R_{3}\rightarrow R_{3}-3R_{1}
\end{array}\end{array}}\\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
1 & 1 & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & -\frac{5}{2} & -\frac{3}{2} & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow[R_{3}\rightarrow R_{3}+R_{2}]{R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}-R_{2}}\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -\frac{7}{2} & -\frac{5}{2} & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow{R_{3}\rightarrow\left(-\frac{2}{7}\right)R_{3}}\\
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
1 & 0 & \frac{5}{2} & \frac{3}{2} & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]\xrightarrow[R_{4}\rightarrow R_{4}+R_{3}]{\begin{array}{c}
R_{1}\rightarrow R_{1}-\frac{5}{2}R_{3}\\
R_{2}\rightarrow R_{2}+R_{3}
\end{array}}\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & \frac{5}{7} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{7} & \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 1
\end{array}\right]
\end{array}$

Where is the mistake here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the last step, $R_4$ is wrong, it should be
$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & \frac{5}{7} & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -\frac{2}{7} & \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{5}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 0\\
0& 0& 0&\color{blue}{\mathbf{-\frac{2}{7}}} & -\frac{2}{7} & -\frac{2}{7} & 1
\end{array}\right].$$